# adobe air licensing library

Tags: air, licensing

I am looking for a licensing library for adobe air.
[Sharify](http://www.sharify.it/) looks like a very capable and easy library but it is in (closed) beta.
Please let me know if you now of other libraries, services or methods to monetize your adobe air app.

Comment: Sharify seems really good, it's not just a library but a service.

Comment: Thx Alix. It is a service too. Excellent point, to make things clearer, I would rather not depend on an external service but have the means to generate (monitor and track) the license myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has something codenamed "Shibuya" http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shibuya/ which will let you do licensing.

Right now it's in prerelease but if you sign up, you can send me an email and I'll make sure you're added.

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com

Comment: Thanx Ryan. I applied will send you my email directly.
Any other services you know (and as an adobe employee you can recommend ;-) )?